# NShape - create custom shape which is a polyline + text

Tags: .net, diagram

NSHAPE: https://nshape.codeplex.com/

Question:
Is it possible to extend the polyline, so it always has some text to the right of the line? (or is there already a control for this)

I've read over the 'create your own shape' docs, but am struggling to see how to connect a line and text shape.

I partly understand the source code, so if someone could point in the right direction of where to edit that would be great.

Comment: did you ever manage to fix this problem.? I am running into the same issue.